# CountDownTimer gets Reset or refreshed on fragment Change

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, countdowntimer

I have build an Android application, where I'm using CountDownTimer, everything works fine. Every time I change switch from a different fragment to the current one
the CountDownTimer gets reset.

and i am running this in an ArrayAdapter.

How to keep running this CountDownTimer one switching fragments or even app close and open? I am also using SharedPreferences for saving data.

my sample Code is here for reference :

```
 startTimer11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

      float sonuc2 = floatET1 * 60;

            DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
            format.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false);

            Log.e("HEHEHEHE", String.valueOf(format.format(sonuc2)));

            String getMinutes = String.valueOf(format.format(sonuc2));//Get minutes from edittexf

            if (!getMinutes.equals("") && getMinutes.length() > 0) {
                int noOfMinutes = Integer.parseInt(getMinutes) * 60 * 1000;//Convert minutes into milliseconds


                countDownTimer[0] = new CountDownTimer(noOfMinutes, 1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                        //Convert milliseconds into hour,minute and seconds
                        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
                        countdownTimerText11.setText(hms);//set text
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {


                        countdownTimerText11.setText("TIME'S UP!!"); //On finish change timer text
                        countdownTimerText11.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        countDownTimer[0] = null;//set CountDownTimer to null

                    }
                }.start();


                startTimer.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.stop_timer));

            } else
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please enter no. of Minutes.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Display toast if edittext is empty
        } else {
            //Else stop timer and change text
            if (countDownTimer[0] != null) {
                countDownTimer[0].cancel();
                countDownTimer[0] = null;

            }
            startTimer11.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.start_timer));
        }

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        alertDialog.cancel();
    }
});
```

Comment: do you mean by close : the completely kill the app or do change from app to another for example ?

Comment: yes kill the app

Comment: You can do that with kill the app, only if you use server for doing that, and fetch the data from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the time they clicked the button to start the timer to the shared preferences.

You can then use that as the time started and calculate the elapsed time by getting the difference between this and the current time.

Comment: thank you for the suggested solution.. but i am not sure how to do that, is there any example u have?